# What Gary fisher model is this?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Repainted so pictures won’t help.  Sn looks like T8T-1123 second row C44EMO15.  24 speed aluminum about 16.5 frame with Alivio derailleur.  Original color was black with yellow trim.

Thanks for any help

Kip

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Pictures _will_ help, much more than a serial number; please include them.